# Get the percentage of a certain category

Tags: probability, percentages

I have news belonging to 4 categories like sports,movie,politics and current-affairs. Now suppose if I got my total result of news as 45 which belongs all these 4 categories ie

```
sports - 10
movie - 5
politics - 10
current-affairs - 20
```

How to find the total percentage out of 100 of this news count which has total 45 in number and categories 4. I know that to find the probability of sports

```
P(sports)=10/45
```

But my question is after calculating these probabilities can we convert it into percentages???

Comment: @hardmath   yes there is no overlap....and even if it occurs it's not a big problem

Comment: Nur 100% sure I got your question right, but you just have to multiply the probability by 100 to get the percentages. You already calculated that P(sports)=10/45. Thus the percentage of sports news=(10/45)*100=200/9=22.2222...%. Similar for the others (movie=11.1111...% politics=22.2222...% and current-affairs=44.44....%)